# How to create a label variable from a binary matrix with multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I am trying to get a label variable from a binary matrix (df). The df matrix has multiple columns (n=981), and I want to get a categorical variable with 3 especific labels based on all the df columns.

First, I created a small matrix and tried with the next code:

```
           X543.4       X543.5     X543.6      X543.7      X543.8      X543.9      X543.10     X543.11      X543.12 
ab         1            1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
afc        0            0           0           0           0           1           0           0           1
dhaa       1            1           1           1           0           0           0           0           0
cafa       1            1           0           1           0           1           0           0           0
ashs       1            0           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
ahsa       1            1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
```

my_sample_col <- data.frame(sample = rep(c("Bacteria A", " Bacteria B", "Bacteria C"), c(2,3,4)))

row.names(my_sample_col) <- colnames(df)

my_sample_col

```
sample
X543.4  Bacteria A
X543.5  Bacteria A
X543.6  Bacteria B
X543.7  Bacteria B
X543.8  Bacteria B
X543.9  Bacteria C
X543.10 Bacteria C
X543.11 Bacteria C
X543.12 Bacteria C
```

However, these results are not the correct labels for each column of the df matrix.

Correct labels must be as below:

```
        sample
X543.4  Bacteria B
X543.5  Bacteria C
X543.6  Bacteria B
X543.7  Bacteria C
X543.8  Bacteria C
X543.9  Bacteria A
X543.10 Bacteria C
X543.11 Bacteria A
X543.12 Bacteria C
```

I was wondering if someone could help me to fix this error.

Finally, I would like to get a categorical variable with 3 especific labels considering all the columns (n=981). I have 981 columns coded and know which code groups belong to a specific label.  I

Please, I would be very grateful by their awesome help.

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show example instead of images. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the question is completely clear.  How do you associate values A, B, C to the columns?

Comment: Thank you for your response Arthur. I have a binary matrix with 981 columns (named in codes). Columns represent samples obtained from 3 bacterial species. I want to get a categorical variable with 3 especific labels based on all the columns (n=981).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already updated the question. Please, I will be very grateful by your awesome help.